# New document only accept document template when it is created by ribbon

Tags: office-365

I've created default document template for document library successfully and placed Document property in the template.
Now when I create new document using Ribbon it takes document template correctly. and placed pre-defined added Document Property.[image]

But When I create document from shortcut button, it doesn't accept default template and creates blank document
[image]

Can Anyone explain difference between this two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to ensure that you enable content types on your library.

1. Go to the library settings > advanced settings > allow management of content types, and select Yes
2. Create a new site content type that inherits from Document and attach your document template to that.
3. Add the new content type to the list of content types for the library.

Comment: mine are 16.0.5104.1206

Comment: Just realised I was on the wrong track. I've re-written answer in regards to using content types on your library, which I had previously assumed!

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between `New Document` command in Ribbon and so-called `+New control` is that `+New control` is connected to Office Web Apps, opens `Create a new file` dialog box on click, and gets replaced by `+New document` as soon as content type management is enabled in the library.

There's a [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2911760) on this behavior.

If you want to change that behavior, follow @PaulLucas's advise or consult [this article at support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-multiple-Office-templates-to-a-document-library-cde94e90-a1ba-4b94-a187-600ed68562bb) - simply turn on content types.

---

I prefer to think of `+New` control as of something more suitable for simple use cases - no defined content types, and nothing like IRM, information policies, customized templates. Just a friendly way for users to get used to Word/Excel Online.