# IRM and new documents from scratch best practices scenarios

Tags: document-library, content-type, irm, new-experience

do you know by chance is there any kind of blog or notes how to establish managed content types to have a good experience for the end user?
We have 3 templates per Word, Excel, PowerPoint, OpenNote documents, and we would like the user has ability to start document from that templates.

I setup the content types in the content type hub and then added to a library with IRM setting.
I faced an issue the word templates must be .docx format (not the dotx) - it created a file and showed an unknown error opening it in word online.

Other issue was actually to realize difference between the +New button and the New Document in the ribbon. ([Aziz Kabyshev's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/173881/new-document-only-accept-document-template-when-it-is-created-by-ribbon/173897#173897) and [a short article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_web_apps_server_2013_support_blog/2014/03/12/irm-information-rights-management-features-and-limitations-using-office-web-apps-on-premise/) gave a clue about it and why the rows about Word, Excel,... disappeared  after setting up the IRM)

A next, this time "not found answer issue", is the being started Word 2016 opened the template but on Save (shows correctly the location of the lib (with all existing files) but on save silently (without error message) didn't upload anything in the library?